# How to make a Command Block search and clear Item from player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make sort of a command block trade shop thing. I've got it working with these commands in a chain of command blocks:

```
execute as @a if data entity @s {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:5b}]} run tag @s add lostDoubloon

clear @p[tag=lostDoubloon] minecraft:diamond 5

give @a[tag=lostDoubloon] sunflower 1

tag @p[tag=lostDoubloon] remove lostDoubloon
```

This works as it removes 5 diamonds and gives 1 sunflower. But it only does this if there is a EXACTLY 5 diamond stack in the inventory. If it is anything above or less this doesn't work. How can I make it so that it works even if the diamonds are spread in the inventory or has more than 5 in a stack? I tried this but it didn't seem to work:

```
execute as @a store result score @s itemsCleared run clear @s minecraft:diamond 0
tag @a[scores={itemsCleared=5}] add lostDoubloon
```

I feel like I'm really close but I don't know where I'm going wrong. Please help~!

Comment: We just had a similar question, but i cannot find it. I'm sure this one will get closed as a duplicate, though, so you might want use our search function. Good luck!

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/o2msb1/minecraft_count_items_in_inventory/) could possibly help. Basically, store the result of `clear @s item 0` into a scoreboard and work from there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a command block shop that allows players to sell items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/252910/how-do-i-make-a-command-block-shop-that-allows-players-to-sell-items)

Comment: Other possible duplicate targets: [Is there a way to make it so the /clear command takes a certain amount of items with a strict amount?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/286181/185203), [How to test for minimum amount of items in inventory and execute a command if true](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/354315/185203), [How can I specify a count that's greater than or equal to a given number in a command?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/398971/185203)

Comment: As you can see, I've fallen into a rabbit hole (and cast three duplicate close votes on longstanding questions) trying to prove @Joachim right.

Comment: @pppery Ain't that just the way :) (I was thinking of the last suggested duplicate you refer to, which is probably the most recent. This is also a good time to once again thank you for all your efforts getting dupes closed!)